# move_uploaded_file(): Permission denied

Tags: php, linux, permisos

ojalá puedan echarme una mano con este problema:

**CONTEXTO.** Trabajo en un servidor Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server v.7.8 (Maipo). PHP 7.0.33 y CodeIgniter 3. Todas las sub-carpetas dentro de /var/www/html/mi/sitio/uploads/ tienen los mismos permisos: 755 y todas tienen establecido como propietario y grupo a "root".

**QUÉ QUIERO HACER.** Estoy armando un plugin encargado de optimizar imágenes y guardarlas dentro de la carpeta "uploads" ya mencionada.

**PROBLEMA.** Las imágenes se guardan bien si uso la librería `$this->load->library('upload')`. Pero si las intento guardar "a mano" usando la función nativa de PHP move_uploaded_file(), PHP devuelve el siguiente error: Permission denied. Si ejecuto is_writable() a la carpeta donde quiero guardar las imágenes, is_writable() devuelve siempre FALSE.

**QUÉ HE INTENTADO.**

1. He ejecutado `chcon -R --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t /path/to/your/directory`
2. Me he asegurado que los archivos de código (el controlador y la librería) tengan el mismo grupo y propietario que la carpeta donde quiero que se guarden las imágenes.
3. Finalmente asigné permisos 777 a la carpeta donde quiero que se guarden las imágenes. Y esto es lo único que funciona. Aunque claramente por cuestiones de seguridad no es la mejor alternativa.

¿Qué ajuste podré probar para desaparecer el problema de permisos? ¿En dónde podrá estar el problema?

Cualquier sugerencia o idea es bienvenida!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, han pasado algunos meses después que formulé está pregunta. Una de las cosas que he aprendido desde entonces, es que cuando sale un tema relacionado con permisos, como ese de Permission denied, o de que no se puede acceder a una carpeta/archivo cuando estamos seguros de que sí existen y están presentes, muy probablemente el tema tiene que ver con el propietario, grupo y/o permisos asignados al recurso en cuestión.

En mi caso, mi problema no era que la función de PHP no funcionará, sino que la carpeta donde deberían guardarse los archivos cargados tenía un grupo y propietario tales que no permitían que se leyera ni escribiera en esa carpeta. La cosa se solucionó cambiando el propietario y grupo a apache:apache. No fue necesario asignar permisos riesgosos como 777. Los permisos se quedaron tal como es usual: 645 para archivos y 755 para carpetas.